# allow cross-references in code snippets

Tags: feature-request, code-formatting

When posting a code snippet on StackOverflow, there is a kind of syntax highlight which is cool. But, for some longer code snippets, wouldn't be way cool to have a kind of source x-ref (in the spirit of the report [maven surefire](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-report-plugin/examples/cross-referencing.html) produces) allowing one to have specific highlights in source code for element under cursor.

Answer (score 2):

It's generally discouraged to be posting long code snippets. Certainly code snippets long enough to make use of such a feature. I do like the idea, but the effort/return ratio just isn't there for use on SO.

You can always manually hack in something to get the point across. I.e., see (1) in my code below:

```
public void x()
{
    ...
    int a = 42;  // *** 1 ***
    ...
}
```